# PHP MongoDB insert using loop

Tags: php, mongodb

I am having some trouble working with MongoDB in PHP at the moment.

I am pulling records of financial data from a CSV file almost a gig, I am looping through the file fine and outputting and parsing the array.

During the while loop I am also trying to insert the data in to MongoDB

```
// Increase timeout on php script
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {

    $parsedData['name'] = $data['0'];
    $parsedData['email'] = $data['1'];
    $parsedData['phone'] = $data['2'];
    $parsedData['address'] = $data['3'];
    $parsedData['gender'] = $data['4'];

    $collection->insert($parsedData);

}
```

So the problem is that it inserts only one of the records or a few, I can't really say it seems quite random.

Any help here would be great.

**Tests Completed**

- Running the same function while testing with mysql returned successful.
- print_r($parsedData) displays desired values.
- Wrapping $collection->insert in an if statement returns true

Comment: what is `$parsedData`?

Comment: Are you running this from command line? Because depending on your server there is generally a timeout of 30 seconds.

Comment: I am curling this and also have the following at the top of the model

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

Comment: @Livewire update timeout seconds, even if it was timing out I should be getting more than one record in the db?

Comment: Without seeing anything, I can only guess the data file has bad line breaks or line breaks the PHP function fgetcsv() cannot parse.

Comment: @kalinma It seems to be passing the data correctly as I have limited the loop to 10 and is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I managed to resolve this issue after reading more on some MongoDB documentation.

1. I wrapped the procedure with a try and catch adding an exception
2. Added fsync and safe to the array that was sent to MongoDB
3. The final piece added was "new MongoId" as MongoDB was returning duplicate _id (as far as I know this was the only necessary step to take)

   ```
   while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {
       try{ 

           // Add MongoId, without this it was returning a duplicate key 
           // error in the catch.
           $parsedData['_id'] =  new MongoId();

           $parsedData['name'] = $data['0'];
           $parsedData['email'] = $data['1'];
           $parsedData['phone'] = $data['2'];
           $parsedData['address'] = $data['3'];
           $parsedData['gender'] = $data['4'];

           // Submitted "safe" and "fsync" with the array, as far as I
           // can see MongoDB waits till data is entered before it sends
           // a true response instead of continuing after the function is 
           // executed.
           $collection->save($parsedData, array('safe' => true, 'fsync' => true));


       }catch(MongoCursorException $e){
           // This is where I caught the duplicate id
           print_r($e->doc['err']);

           // Kill the procedure
           die();
       }
   }
   ```

If anyone can add to this it would be great as I thought Mongo generated its own id's and that it would only return true when data is entered or maybe I'm just expecting it to run similar to the MySQL drivers.

Comment: I always appreciate it when someone who finds their own answer posts it for the benefit of others. Good to know about the difference between Mongo and MySQL regarding unique ids.